# Hurwitz numbers and Hurwitz theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Am currently doing a self-study of hurwitz numbers and Hurwitz theory, is there a good source for one with only basic knowledge of algebraic geometry. Notes and papers are also welcome.

Comment: There was a course on Hurwitz numbers at the UC Davis a few years ago: http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~mulase/courses/mat280f09.html Somewhere down that page (next to "References") it says: "We intend to produce lecture notes to be published". Maybe you can ask Prof. Mulase if they ever came to existence. If so, I would love to read them, too :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a nice exposition by Renzo Cavalieri that I often recommend to students:

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/IMPA.pdf